# Herb identification

Tags: flowers, herbs

I received a dried herb from amazon that I didn't order. I have many packages at the moment so my boyfriend opened and trew the packaging thinking is just another one that came. I cannot send it back and I have no idea what it is. Does anybody recognizes this herb?? It smells a little bit like cow.
Thank you [image]

[

1. [image]

][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rotbr.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's intended purpose might not be food (so, I wouldn't eat it).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you let Amazon know, because it might be a brushing scam, see here https://clark.com/shopping-retail/amazon-scam-brushing-warning-deliveries-you-didnt-order/. Unsolicited 'brushing' items sent like this are usually cheap things like inexpensive earrings or unidentified seeds or something but either way, I wouldn't be using whatever's in that bag for anything.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Plus @Andreea you might want to search for your name on Amazon to see whether your name pops up next to the stellar reviews of some random product (TBH it looks like the "herb" is just a bunch of randomly-picked, dried leaves stuffed into a plastic bag).